# Is there a way to control Nuget's over-eager references?

Tags: nuget

I'm just getting started with Nuget, and moving much of my team's intra-team and interdepartmental references into packages on a private nuget feed. The thing I'm observing though is that when my packages have their own dependencies, those secondary dependencies get added to my projects as references as though the projects are using them directly.

This works from a build & release perspective since the dependencies get packaged up correctly, but for larger projects the references list gets rather bloated compared to the assemblies actually referenced in code. In a hypothetical cleanup exercise, it seems like it would be difficult to determine which assemblies were this type of secondary dependency and which were simply no longer used.

Is this just an unfortunate consequence of Nuget works? Is there a different way to use Nuget that doesn't result in these noisy references?

For example: I have project MyProject, which uses assembly DependencyA directly. DependencyA references assembly LibraryX and as such LibraryX is required at runtime for MyProject, even though MyProject doesn't use it directly. For the sake of the example let's say LibraryX is distinct enough for it to be its own package.

In this scenario, prior to Nuget, the assemblies would live in source control, and could be packaged up during build/publish/deploy without needing an assembly reference in MSBuild. In this case MyProject has an MSBuild assembly reference to DependencyA, but not to LibraryX.

However, upon migrating to Nuget and consuming these dependencies via packages, the nuspec for DependencyA expresses a dependeny on LibraryX:

```
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>DependencyA</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Initech</authors>
    <owners>Initech</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">MIT</license>
    <description>A Dependency</description>
    <tags>Dependency A</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net40" >
        <dependency id="LibraryX" version="1.0.0" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

When installing the DependencyA package on MyPrject, Nuget adds an MSBuild assembly reference for LibraryX to MyProject even though MyProject doesn't actually directly reference LibraryX.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a (maybe real life) example on the dependencies you have and how they are pulled in? When they are dependencies you cannot "clean them up", they are still required by the library your are using.

Comment: @Progman Took a stab at it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The references are somehow required, otherwise you can't compile the project or you can't run the application because the dependencies are missing. Or do you have a different goal in mind on how to resolve the dependencies later on? What do you want to avoid and why?

Comment: That's not the case--you can compile the project without references to your dependency's dependencies, in this case you can compile MyProject without a reference to LibraryX because MyProject doesn't reference it. LibraryX is required only at runtime, not compile time. Using Nuget that division between compile-time and runtime dependencies is gone.

Comment: Which project/solution format do you use? When I have a project with the [SDK format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format#check-the-project-format) and add the nuget package "MessagePack" in version `2.1.115` it will only add that specific `PackageReference` entry in the `.csproj` file, even though it has a dependency on ["MessagePack.Annotations"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MessagePack), which is pulled in (but not referenced). Can you add the `.csproj` (or other) project file you have which shows the difference before and after adding the NuGet package?

Comment: Unfortunately my project configuration (specifically ASP.NET) isn't supported for PackageReference, so if I'm reading this correctly the PrivateAssets configuration isn't available to me. After using Install-Package via the Package Management Console, my project's packages.config is modified and a normal old Reference element is added in MSBuild, with a HintPath element pointed to the packages folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can control which assets are allowed to flow up the dependency chain using [`PrivateAssets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#includeassets-excludeassets-and-privateassets), which I think is what you mean.

By default everything flows up though, so you can use packages you only depend on transitively in your code - in other words, the distinction between compile and runtime dependencies you mentioned in your comment doesn't exist by default.

Comment: Unfortunately my project configuration (specifically ASP.NET) isn't supported for PackageReference, so if I'm reading this correctly the PrivateAssets configuration isn't available to me. I'm hoping to find some nuanced way of producing the package.

Comment: To be honest even if you have it I don't think you can really achieve what you want to, as you don't have control over how your dependencies reference their dependencies. It's not clear why you're trying to achieve this, but you'll be fighting all the tooling which is never a good plan